# Retrieving values from a chain of ADT's with Maybe's

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have some ADT's each of which may or not contain another ADT. I need to retrieve data from lower levels and I'm writing some very repetitive code which I am sure can be eliminated. I've looked at some example code in Real World Haskell and in "Learn You a Haskell For Great Good" but I can't quite figure it out. Here is an example with irrelevent details of the ADT's left out.

```
  T24Report
      - projTitle :: Maybe ProjectTitle
            - zip :: Maybe String
```

To retrieve the zip code from StreetAddress I've been ending up with this:

```
 projNameStr :: T24Report -> String
 projNameStr t24 = if isNothing projTitleMaybe
                    then ""
                    else (fromMaybe "") $ zip $ fromJust projTitleMaybe
                where
                    projTitleMaybe = projTitle $ project t24
```

As the depth of the chain of objects increases, the repetitiveness of the code does too. There must be a better way. Ideas? References? I couldn't find a similar question on StackOverflow, but I believe it must be here...this seems like an simple problem that must have been asked.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Sounds like you ought to be using `Maybe` as a monad.

Comment: Take a look at the `maybe` function, case analysis, and Maybe's Monad/Applicative instance. Personally, I rarely use `isNothing` or `fromJust`.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll go re-read the information on monad's and see if I can wrap my head around it.

Comment: The Control.Lens library (or lenses in general) might be very helpful in this case, especially if you are wanting to change a nested record. It can be tedious to reconstruct a new instance of the type from the inside out representing the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd write that, in the most generic case, something like:

```
projNameStr :: T24Report -> String
projName t24 = fromMaybe "" $ do
    title <- projTitle $ project t24
    zip title
```

The key point is using a `do` block to factor out handling all of the `Nothing` cases.

However, in this specific case, since there are only the two `Maybe`s in the chain, I'd be tempted to shorten it a bit:

```
projNameStr :: T24Report -> String
projName t24 = fromMaybe "" $ projTitle (project t24) >>= zip
```

That's exactly what the previous example is converted to during compilation. Usually that sort of manual desugaring makes things worse, not better. But in this case, I would be tempted to go with this, just because it's a couple lines shorter and not *too much* more work to read.

Comment: And now I can and so I did. Thanks again @Carl

Answer (score 6):

Maybe's monad instance is built for solving this exact problem. If you have some objects, maybeX, maybeY and maybeZ with types Maybe a, Maybe b and Maybe c respectively, you can do this

```
do x <- maybeX
   y <- maybeY
   z <- maybeZ
   return (x,y,z)
```

This will have the type Maybe (a,b,c), if any of the three Maybes was Nothing, the final result will be Nothing.

So, in your example, you would do something like this

```
projNameStr t24 = fromMaybe "" $ do t <- projTitle t24
                                    zip t
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I figured I was overlooking the obvious. I'd upvote your answer...but I'm under the 15 required reputation points

Comment: @tim93422: Now you can. :)

Comment: @Vitus, and now I did. Thanks again!